# Run program when cpu resources below percentage

Tags: c#

I want a program that I'm writing to execute on certain dates set by the user and also when CPU resources fall below a certain %. Right now, I am using Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper
(http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/documentation) to set up a Windows Scheduled task with the date and time a user specifies.

However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do the CPU % part. Is it even possible to set up a Windows Scheduled Task to do this? If not, how would I do it? Windows service?

Comment: are you familiar with WMI..? this may be a good place to start

Comment: Why don't you simply use `thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest` ?